# Display diagram with hyperlinks

Tags: 2013, powerpoint

How can I display a clickable diagram on a SharePoint 2013 page?

This is what I have tried:

I made a diagram in PowerPoint 2010 and added hyperlinks to the individual boxes in the diagram. Then I uploaded it using Insert > Upload file:

[image]

However this only results in a silly little icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create image maps in the page . For creating simple image maps .Try using html `<map>` tag . Check this example for [creating simple image maps](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

For much more advanced graphical user interfaces for image maps. There are jquery plugins available which you can included in your content editor.